# создать программу, которая спрашивает "сколько вам лет"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка. не могу понять. язык с++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   
    printf() << ("How old are you?");
    string myAge;
    scanf >> (myAge);
    printf << ("you are " << myAge << " years old");
    return 0;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Вавилонское смещение яз*ы*ков... `scanf`, `printf` — это из С, это функции... `cout << "How old are you?"`,  `cin >> myAge;`...

Comment: Не пытайтесь угадать правильную запись, не получится. Перечитайте начало вашей книжки по С++, там должны быть примеры...

Comment: Вы об этом в вопросе не упомянули.

Comment: значит использовать син и сяу?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("How old are you? ");
    int myAge;
    scanf("%d",&myAge);
    printf("You are %d years old",myAge);
}
```

Comment: Сам хотел дать, опередили меня буквально на несколько секунд)))

Answer (score 0):

Cмотри, ты совместил несколько типов ввода-вывода
нужно либо

```
printf("");
scanf();
```

либо

```
cout << "";
cin >> ;
```

если делать прогу через `cout`, то она будет выглядеть +- вот так

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
   
    cout << "How old are you? ";
    string myAge;
    cin >> (myAge);
    cout << "you are " <<  myAge << " years old";
    return 0;
    
}
```